# Unity C#, WWWForm post to Python Flask Server

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine

Hi I am making a game in unity and I need to post information to my python flask server I think that the best method is to use the WWWForms in Unity C# but I can't seem to make it post. Here is my C# Unity Code:

```
IEnumerator Upload() {
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("Username", "Stan");
    form.AddField("Password", "123456");

    using(UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://myserver.com/newuser/", form)) {
        yield return www.Send();

        if(www.isError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

It alsways says "From upload complete" and I don't get any errors but when I check my SQL Database it hasn't received the information.

I am pretty sure that my server side code is right because I can post successfully to it through the Form but here is the code anyway:

Python Flask:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "userstable"
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(4096))
    password = db.Column(db.String(4096))

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/newuser", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def NewUser():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("NewUser.html")
    new_user = Users(username=request.form["Username"], password=request.form["Password"])
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('NewUser'))
```

Please Help, and if possible it would be nice to know how to do get requests as well, Thanks!

Stan.

Comment: Can't really comment on how your Python end works, but I've used PHP for my server side code before. The way Unity handled POST request parameters is by sticking it in the `$_FILES` superglobal, rather than the usual `$_POST` superglobal array. Maybe there's something similar in Python you can look at

Comment: I don't think that that is the issue, although i have a had some really weird things where i doesn't send anything and then all of a sudden sends the request like 100 times after the program is off although that has only happened twice out of the hundreds of times i have run the code